# What is the correct projection to use with tm_wgs84_sans_antarctica.shp?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, mapnik, google-maps-api

I am using [tm_wgs84_sans_antarctica.shp](http://mapnik-utils.googlecode.com/svn/data/) with mapnik to generate tiles. I am using the tiles with [Google Maps Javascript API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference). But the projection is way off. Here is roughly what my code looks like:

```
import mapnik
m = mapnik.Map(
      tile.size()[0],
      tile.size()[0],
      )
s = mapnik.Style()
r = mapnik.Rule()

polygon_symbolizer = mapnik.PolygonSymbolizer(mapnik.Color('#f2eff9'))
r.symbols.append(polygon_symbolizer)
s.rules.append(r)

m.append_style('My Style',s)

ds = mapnik.Shapefile(file='tm_wgs84_sans_antarctica.shp')
layer = mapnik.Layer('world')
layer.datasource = ds
layer.styles.append('My Style')
m.layers.append(layer)

bbox = tile.bounds()
bbox = mapnik.Box2d(bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3])
m.zoom_to_box(bbox)
im = mapnik.Image( *tile.size() )
mapnik.render(m, im)
```

As you can see I am not setting any srs either in map or in layer. I tried different combination of projection strings without really understanding what they mean, but either got no map or wrongly projected map. Please let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks.

Comment: is there a prj file with the shp and dbf files? If so it should have the projection information in the prj file. It is in text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [prj file](http://mapnik-utils.googlecode.com/svn/data/tm_wgs84_sans_antarctica.prj) has this:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

Using srs `+init=epsg:4326` which is defined as:

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

fixed the problem. Now the shape file gets rendered fine with google maps.